# How I can get flex-messaging-client-android.jar?

Tags: java, android, adobe, amf, dataservice

How I can get flex-messaging-client-android.jar? 
please provide a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["Creating an Android application that invokes Data Services"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/enterpriseplatform/10.0/AEPDeveloperGuide/WS4976f0ec3ef48246-1c24bbe312dc391a64f-8000.html) page says that this JAR is in "dataservices-sdk-pkg.zip" which you can retrieve from the "Experience Server".  A link on how to download that is on the page.

The jar is also floating around various 3rd-party download sites ... if you are willing to take the risk of a nastyware infestation.

Comment: It is a long story to download that zip file, there is no download link to it. you have to download libraries and plugins then create an ID at labs.adobe.com then you can download the zip file from a localhost link.

Comment: @hasan - it is your choice, but are you prepared to risk you, your company and/or your customers' data on a JAR whose origin is questionable?  Personally, there is no question.  Grit your teeth and do it the way Adobe expect you to do it.